# Mobile site-content being mushed

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, mobile-website

Im coding a website for myself (Jerico) and decided to test it on mobile but all the content is shoved to the left. I tried using meta-viewport and tweacking CSS but it doesn't work. Can someone help me get the website not all mushed together on mobile?

I've spent like 9 hours coding this for no reason and doing research and can't figure anything out. Please help.

Here is my website and Github for it:
jericogit.github.io/Jerico/Index.html
https://github.com/JericoGit/Jerico

Answer (score 2):

There a few reasons why you're website is doing that on mobile. I can see that you're using flexbox which is a good start but there are things that can be done to make it wrap properly. I will note though that some people prefer grids, but I prefer flexbox, so I'll make suggestions based on that.

First, for the body I like to add overflow: hidden; to stop any overhang on the website.

```
body {
  /* your css */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Next, we can tackle the content squishing. There are at least two easy ways to approach it.

**Option 1**
I use this option sometimes, but I prefer option #2. In this one you're applying the flex-wrap: wrap; property, essentially telling all the children in the parent to wrap to the next line when there isn't enough page space.

```
.cards {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**Option 2**
I like do to do a combo of media queries, I find it looks cleaner.

```
.cards {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .cards {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Your design will look much cleaner if you the following sizing trick:

1. Apply width: 100%; to the element
2. Set a max-width: ###em/px/etc.

This way your elements will look more uniform, and will grow from small screen sizes up to your maximum.

In terms of other changes to help with cleaner responsive design:

- You can use the CSS gap property instead of margins around the elements
- I don't know of many, if any good reasons to use a fixed height on your elements. If you don't remove the fixed height from .card, then the text will overlap other elements. If you *must* have fixed heights, you can add overflow-y: auto; to control that; but note that's not great UX.

---

**EDIT**

```
.cards {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 40px;
}

.card {
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to accept access and submit a pull request?

Comment: I edited the original post; just replace your .cards and .card CSS with this css

It might also help to add * {box-sizing: border-box;} in your global.css

Comment: That will fix all the sizing? Even the header being super small and stuff on mobile?

Comment: This will fix your .cards element only. Your header looked fine to me, but if you needed to change it, just apply the same principles I wrote in my answer. Use media queries if you need to be specific and use flex-box to control positioning.

Comment: I decided to take your approach and another to fix my problem, I started using `calc()` `vh`, and `vw` a lot to make things look well cross-platform.